# Congruations - relations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Is

$3n+2 \equiv 0 \bmod 4$  same as

$3n-6 \equiv 0 \bmod 4$ ?

I think it's the same thing because $2$ and $-6$  have the same remainder when divided with $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct:\begin{align}3n+2\equiv3n-6\pmod4&\iff(3n+2)-(3n-6)\equiv0\pmod4\\&\iff8\equiv0\pmod4,\end{align}which is true, since $4\mid8$.

Answer (score 1):

In general: $$a\equiv b\mod4\iff4\mid a-b$$

So the statements $3n+2\equiv 0\mod4$ and $3n-6\equiv 0\mod4$ can be translated into
$4\mid 3n+2$ and $4\mid 3n-6$.

It is not difficult to prove that these statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $\!\bmod m\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{y\equiv y'}\ \ \Rightarrow\,\ \ x+\color{#c00}y\equiv x+\color{#c00}{y'}$

because $\,\ \  m\,\mid \color{#c00}{y-y'}\!\Rightarrow m\mid x\!+\!y\!-\!(x\!+\!y') = \color{#c00}{y-y'}$

This law is known as the $ $ [Congruence Sum Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).